# Solve the system of linear inequalities with parameters

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of inequalities
\begin{cases}
0\leq \phantom{-2\;}x+2\,y-3\,b+3\,a \leq 2 \\
0\leq -2\,x-3\,y+6\,b\phantom{\;+3a\;\,} \leq 1 \\[4pt]
0 \leq x \leq 1 \\   
0 \leq y \leq 2 \\[4pt]
0\leq a \leq 1 \\
0\leq b \leq 1 \tag{*}
\end{cases}
Here $x,y$ are unknown variables and $a,b$ are parameters.

My attempt. By adding the inequalities with some coeficients I separated the variables and get the simple system
\begin{cases}
0 \leq y+6a \leq 5,\\
0 \leq -x+9a+3b\leq 8.\\ \tag{**}
\end{cases}
and I am able to solve it. But the solutions of the last system  are not solution of the initial system!

Maple and wolframAlpha cant solve the system.

Any help?

P.S.1 For $a=\frac{63}{100}$ and $b=\frac{59}{100}$  ( as at G Cab's picture  below ) Maple gives the solutions
\begin{gather*}
 \left\{ x=1,{\frac{9}{50}}\leq y,y\leq {\frac{11}{25}} \right\} , \left\{ x=-3/2\,y+{\frac{127}{100}},{\frac{9}{50}}<y,y<{\frac{11}{25}} \right\} ,  \left\{ {\frac{9}{50}}<y,x<1,y<{\frac{11}{25}},-3/2\,y+{
\frac{127}{100}}<x \right\} , \left\{ y={\frac{11}{25}},{\frac{61}{100
}}\leq x,x<1 \right\} , \left\{ x=-3/2\,y+{\frac{127}{100}},{\frac{11}
{25}}<y,y<{\frac{127}{150}} \right\} ,  \left\{ {\frac{11}{25}}<y,x<-2
\,y+{\frac{47}{25}},y<{\frac{127}{150}},-3/2\,y+{\frac{127}{100}}<x
 \right\} , \left\{ x=-2\,y+{\frac{47}{25}},{\frac{11}{25}}<y,y<{\frac
{127}{150}} \right\} , \left\{ x=0,{\frac{127}{150}}\leq y,y\leq {
\frac{47}{50}} \right\} , \left\{ y={\frac{127}{150}},x\leq {\frac{14}
{75}},0<x \right\} , \left\{ 0<x,{\frac{127}{150}}<y,x<-2\,y+{\frac{47
}{25}},y<{\frac{47}{50}} \right\} , \\ \left\{ x=-2\,y+{\frac{47}{25}},{
\frac{127}{150}}<y,y<{\frac{47}{50}} \right\}
\end{gather*}

P.P.S. I am interested in finding not the whole set of solutions but in finding at least one solution from the area, if it exists,  but in terms $a$ and $b$, for example, $x=(a+b)/2, y=(2a-b)/10$ is a solution.

Comment: The two inequalities you call "simple system" are indeed consequences of the initial system. What specifically did you get for the solution(s) of the "simple system", that you think are not solutions of the initial system? Seems an error might have crept in when you solved the simple system...

Comment: the region of solutions of $(**)$ is a rectangle   but the region of solutions of $(*)$  in the general case is not rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure if you like this idea, but if you separate it into cases, you can find the  exact shape of the region (a triangle, a pentagon etc.) of solutions of $(*)$. (Also,  you can find $(a,b)$ such that the system has no solutions.) The problem of this idea might be that there are many cases, but the idea itself is simple and the way to separate is not difficult. If you like this idea, I might try :)

Comment: @mathlove. Try solve the simplified problem - for any $a$ and $b$ find  one solution $(x,y)$, see edited post

Comment: @Leox: *"I am interested in finding not the whole set of solutions but in finding at least one solution from the area"* ... You seem to be changing the specific requirement of your question after it has already received answers. Doing so is inconsiderate to answerers whose responses now seem incomplete (and who may receive downvotes as a result). If you have found that your question has not clearly articulated your intent, then the better course of action would be to post a new-and-improved question separately (linking to this one for context).

Comment: @Blue  I dont sure that I received anwer and therefore decided to simplify the task.

Comment: @Leox: *"I dont sure that I received anwer and therefore decided to simplify the task."* ... But you *have* received answers. If they are *unsatisfactory* to you for whatever reason, then you don't have to accept them, but altering what you expect from them *after* they have been posted isn't appropriate. In particular, @ GCab's response is detailed and thorough, and was updated a time or two to address clarifications you wanted. Now, it appears you're saying "I've changed my mind about what I'm asking, so all that time and effort you've expended on my behalf was wasted." That's rather rude.

Comment: @Blue OK, maybe you are  right and I will post a new question

Comment: @Leox  So, you want to find one feasible $(x, y)$ of the system (*) having the form of $x = f(a, b)$ and $y = g(a, b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
6b-1\le 2x+3y \le 6b\\
3b-3a \le x+2y \le 2+3b-3a\\
x,y \in[0,1]\tag1
\end{cases}
over the set of the possible pairs $(a,b)\in[0,1]^2.$

$$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\ 1.\quad a-b >\dfrac23.}}$$

The system $(1)$ **does not have solutions.**

$$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\,2.\quad 0\le a \le \min\left[\frac{2+3b}3,1\right].}}\tag2$$

$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\,2.1.\quad  b\in \bigg[0,\dfrac16\bigg],\quad a\in\bigg[0,b\bigg].}}$

The first equation of the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
0 \le 2x+3y \le 6b\\
3b-3a\le x+2y \le 2+3b-3a\tag{3.1}
\end{cases}
over the first quadrant defines the triangle with the vertice $\quad (0,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b).$

The second equation over the first quadrant defines the trapezoid with the vertice

$(3b-3a, 0),\quad (2+3b-3a,0),\quad (0, \frac{2+3b-3a}2),\quad(0, \frac{3b-3a}2).$

Since

- $\ 0 \le 3b-3a\le 3b \le 2+3b-3a,$
- $\ 0 \le \frac{3b-3a}2 \le 2b \le \frac{2+3b-3a}2,$

then the solution is the simplex with the vertice
$(3b-3a, 0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b),\quad (0, \frac{3b-3a}2).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{3b-3a-x}2,0\right),\frac{6b-2x}3\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.1}$$

[image: Solution b=1/8, a=1/10]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac1{10},\quad b=\dfrac18.$

$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\,2.2.\quad  b\in \bigg[0,\dfrac16\bigg],\quad a\in\bigg[b,\dfrac{2+3b}3\bigg].}}$

The first equation of the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
0 \le 2x+3y \le 6b\\
0\le x+2y \le 2+3b-3a\tag{3.2}
\end{cases}
over the first quadrant defines the triangle with the vertice $\quad (0,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b).$

The second equation over the first quadrant defines the triangle with the vertice

$(0,0),\quad (2+3b-3a,0),\quad (0, \frac{2+3b-3a}2).$

Since

- equality $2b = \frac{2+3b-3a}2$ takes place if $a=\frac{2-b}3,$
- equality $3b = 2+3b-3a$ takes place if $a=\frac{2}3,$

then the next cases should be considered.

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.2.1.\quad  b\in \left[0,\dfrac16\right],\quad a\in\bigg[b,\dfrac{2-b}3\bigg].}}$$

Solution is the triangle with the vertice $\quad (0,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[0, \frac{6b-2x}3\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.2.1}$$

[image: Solution b=1/8, 1/8 <= a <= 5/8]

Solution for $\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac1{8},\dfrac58\bigg],\quad b=\dfrac18.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.2.2.\quad  b\in \left[0,\dfrac16\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac{2-b}3,\dfrac23\bigg].}}$$

The lines $2x+3y=6b$ and $x+2y = 2+3b-3a$ have intersection at the point $(x_i,y_i) = (9a+3b-6, 4-6a).$

Solution is the simplex with the vertice $\quad (0,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (9a+3b-6, 4-6a),\quad (0,\frac{2+3b-3a}2).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[0, \min\left(\frac{2+3b-3a-x}2,\frac{6b-2x}3\right)\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.2.2}$$

[image: Solution b=1/8, a = 9/14]

Solution for $\quad a = \dfrac{9}{14},\quad b=\dfrac18.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.2.3.\quad  b\in \left[0,\dfrac16\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac23,\dfrac{2+3b}3\bigg].}}$$

Solution is the triangle with the vertice $\quad (0,0),\quad (2+3b-3a,0),\quad (0,\frac{2+3b-3a}2).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,2+3b-3a\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[0, \frac{2+3b-3a-x}2\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.2.3}$$

[image: Solution b=1/8, a=17/24]

Solution for $\quad a = \dfrac{17}{24},\quad b=\dfrac18.$

$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\,2.3.\quad  b\in \bigg[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\bigg],\quad a\in\bigg[0,b\bigg].}}$

The first equation of the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
6b-1 \le 2x+3y \le 6b\\
3b-3a\le x+2y \le 2+3b-3a\tag{3.3}
\end{cases}
over the first quadrant defines the trapezoid with the vertice $\quad (\frac{6b-1}2,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b),\quad (0,\frac{6b-1}3).$

The second equation over the first quadrant defines the trapezoid with the vertice

$(3b-3a, 0),\quad (2+3b-3a,0),\quad (0, \frac12(2+3b-3a)),\quad (0, \frac12(3b-3a)).$

Since

- equality $\frac{6b-1}3 = \frac{3b-3a}2$ takes place if $a=\frac{2-3b}9,$
- equality $\frac{6b-1}2 = 3b-3a$ takes place if $a=\frac16,$

then the next cases should be considered.

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.3.1.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[0,\dfrac{2-3b}9\bigg].}}$$

Solution is the simplex with the vertice

$(3b-3a,0),\quad (3b, 0),\quad (0,2b),\quad (0, \frac{3b-3a}2).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{3b-3a-x}2,0\right),\frac{6b-2x}3\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.3.1}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=1/12]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac1{12},\quad b=\dfrac14.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.3.2.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac{2-3b}9,\dfrac16\bigg].}}$$

The lines $2x+3y=6b-1$ and $x+2y = 3b-3a$ have intersection at the point $(x_i,y_i) = (9a+3b-2,1-6a).$

Solution is the simplex with the vertice

$(3b-3a,0),\quad (3b, 0),\quad (0,2b),\quad (0, \frac{6b-1}3),\quad (9a+3b-2,1-6a).$

Analytically,
$${\small\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{6b-1-2x}3, \frac{3b-3a-x}2,0\right),\frac{6b-2x}3\bigg]\bigg)}.\tag{4.3.2}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=3/19]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac3{19},\quad b=\dfrac14.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.3.3.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac16,b\bigg].}}$$

Solution is the trapezoid with the vertice

$(3b,0),\quad (3b-3a, 0),\quad (0, \frac{3b-3a}2),\quad (0,2b).$

Analytically,
$$\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{6b-1-2x}3,0\right),\frac{6b-2x}3\bigg]\bigg).\tag{4.3.3}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=1/5]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac15,\quad b=\dfrac14.$

$\color{blue}{\mathbf{Case\,2.4.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[b,b+\dfrac23\bigg].}}$

The first equation of the system in the form of
\begin{cases}
6b-1 \le 2x+3y \le 6b\\
0 \le x+2y \le 2+3b-3a\tag{3.4}
\end{cases}

over the first quadrant defines the trapezoid with the vertice $\quad (\frac{6b-1}2,0),\quad (3b,0),\quad (0,2b),\quad (0,\frac{6b-1}3).$

The second equation over the first quadrant defines the triangle with the vertice

$(0,0),\quad (2+3b-3a,0),\quad (0, \frac{2+3b-3a}2).$

Since

- equality $2b = \frac{2+3b-3a}2$ takes place if $a=\frac{2-b}3,$
- equlaity $3b = 2+3b-3a$ takes place if $a = \frac23,$
- equaity $\frac{6b-1}3 = \frac{2+3b-3a}2$ takes place if $a=\frac{8-3b}9,$
- equaity $\frac{6b-1}2 = 2+3b-3a$ takes place if $a=\frac56,$

then the next cases should be considered.

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.4.1.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[0,\dfrac{2-b}3\bigg].}}$$

Solution is the trapezoid from the paragraph $2.3.3$ above.

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.4.2.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac{2-b}3,\dfrac23  \bigg].}}$$

The lines $2x+3y=6b$ and $x+2y = 2+3b-3a$ have intersection at the point $(x_i,y_i) = (9a+3b-6,4-6a).$

Solution is the simplex with the vertice

$(\frac{6b-1}2,0),\quad (3b, 0),\quad (9a+3b-6,4-6a),\quad (0,\frac{2+3b-3a}2),\quad (0, \frac{6b-1}3).$

Analytically,
$${\small\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,3b\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{6b-1-2x}3,0\right),\min\left(\frac{2+3b-3a-x}2,\frac{6b-2x}3\right)\bigg]\bigg)}.\tag{4.4.2}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=5/8]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac58,\quad b=\dfrac14.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.4.3.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac23,\dfrac{8-3b}9  \bigg].}}$$

Solution is the simplex with the vertice

$(\frac{6b-1}2,0),\quad (2+3b-3a, 0),\quad (0,\frac{2+3b-3a}2),\quad (0, \frac{6b-1}3).$

Analytically,
$${\small\bigg(x\in\bigg[0,2+3b-3a\bigg]\bigg)\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{6b-1-2x}3,0\right),\frac{2+3b-3a-x}2\bigg]\bigg)}.\tag{4.4.3}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=3/4]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac34,\quad b=\dfrac14.$

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{Case\,2.4.4.\quad  b\in \left[\dfrac16,\dfrac13\right],\quad a\in\bigg[\dfrac{8-3b}9,\dfrac56  \bigg].}}$$

The lines $2x+3y=6b-1$ and $x+2y = 2+3b-3a$ have intersection at the point $(x_i,y_i) = (9a+3b-8,5-6a).$

Solution is the triangle with the vertice

$(\frac{6b-1}2,0),\quad (2+3b-3a, 0),\quad (9a+3b-8,5-6a).$

Analytically,
$${\small (x\in[9a+3b-8,2+3b-3a])\wedge\bigg(y\in\bigg[\max\left(\frac{6b-1-2x}3,0\right),\frac{2+3b-3a-x}2\bigg]\bigg)}.\tag{4.4.4}$$

[image: Solution b=1/4, a=14/17]

Solution for $\quad a=\dfrac{14}{17},\quad b=\dfrac14.$

Answer (score 4):

When you have a system of (double) inequalities like this
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a \le x \le b \hfill \cr 
  c \le x \le d \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
you may think that each one represents a segment on the $x$ axis, with the system
standing for AND, i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  x \in \left[ {a,b} \right] \hfill \cr 
  x \in \left[ {c,d} \right] \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x \in \left( {\left[ {a,b} \right] \cap \left[ {c,d} \right]} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad x \in \left[ {\max (a,c),\min \left( {b,d} \right)} \right] \cr} 
$$

Therefore in your case we can do some manipulation as follows
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x + 2y + 3a - 3b \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le  - 2x - 3y + 6b \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le b \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right. \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \left\{ \matrix{
  3\left( {b - a} \right) \le x + 2y \le 3\left( {b - a} \right) + 2 \hfill \cr 
  6b - 1 \le 2x + 3y \le 6b \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le b \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right. \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le b \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  3\left( {b - a} \right) \le x \le 3\left( {b - a} \right) + 2 - 2y \hfill \cr 
  3b - 1/2 - 3/2y \le x \le 6b - 3/2y \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right. \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le b \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  m = \max \left( {3\left( {b - a} \right),3b - 1/2 - 3/2y,0} \right) \hfill \cr 
  n = \min \left( {3\left( {b - a} \right) + 2 - 2y,\;6b - 3/2y,\;1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  m \le x \le n \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

where at the third step we chose to isolate the $x$, but of course we could have done that with $y$
in this case obtaining
$$  
\left\{ \matrix{  
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr   
  0 \le b \le 1 \hfill \cr   
  0 \le x \le 1 \hfill \cr   
  m = \max \left( {3/2\left( {b - a} \right) - x/2 2b - 1/3 - 2/3x 0} \right) \hfill \cr 
  n = \min \left( {3/2\left( {b - a} \right) + 1 - x/2 \;2b - 2/3x \;2} \right) \hfill \cr 
  m \le y \le n \hfill \cr}  \right.  
$$

So, once fixed $a, \; b, \; y$ within the allowed range, we can finish to
compute $x$ in the first case, or viceversa in the second version.

The system sketched in Geogebra gives

[image: Diseq_Syst_1]

*note in reply to your comment*

As you can see from the sketch, the solutions (when they exist) will in general define a 2D area.
Referring to the case depicted, once fixed $a$ and $b$, you can describe the area by having  the $y$ to span the allowed range $[0,2]$
and consequently determine $x$ to be within two bounds, *necessarily depending from $y$*.
There is no possibility to express the bounds on $x$ and $y$ independently from each other.

*example with $a=0.63 ,\; b=0.59$*

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 a = 0.63 \\ 
 b = 0.59 \\ 
 0 \le y \le 2 \\ 
 m = \max \left( { - 0.12,1.27 - 3/2y,0} \right) \\ 
 n = \min \left( {1.88 - 2y,\;3.54 - 3/2y,\;1} \right) \\ 
 m \le x \le n \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\;\; \Rightarrow  \\ 
  \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 0 \le y \le 2 \\ 
 \begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {1.27 - 3/2y \le x \le 1} \hfill & {\left| {\;0 \le y < 0.44} \right.} \hfill  \\
   {1.27 - 3/2y \le x \le 1.88 - 2y} \hfill & {\left| {\;0.44 \le y < 2.54/3} \right.} \hfill  \\
   {0 \le x \le 1.88 - 2y} \hfill & {\left| {\;2.54/3 \le y < 0.94} \right.} \hfill  \\
   {0 \le x \le 1.88 - 2y\; \to \;\emptyset } \hfill & {\left| {\;0.94 \le y \le 2} \right.} \hfill  \\
\end{array} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\; \Rightarrow  \\ 
  \Rightarrow \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {1.27 - 3/2y \le x \le 1} \hfill & {\left| {\;0.18 \le y < 0.44} \right.} \hfill  \\
   {1.27 - 3/2y \le x \le 1.88 - 2y} \hfill & {\left| {\;0.44 \le y < 2.54/3} \right.} \hfill  \\
   {0 \le x \le 1.88 - 2y} \hfill & {\left| {\;2.54/3 \le y < 0.94} \right.} \hfill  \\
\end{array}} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

The second version instead gives the more simple result
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a = 0.63 \hfill \cr 
  b = 0.59 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  m = \max \left( { - 0.06 - x/2,1.18 - 1/3 - 2/3x,0} \right) =  \hfill \cr 
   = 1.18 - 1/3 - 2/3x \hfill \cr 
  n = \min \left( {0.94 - x/2,\;1.18 - 2/3x,\;2} \right) =  \hfill \cr 
   = 0.94 - x/2 \hfill \cr 
  m \le y \le n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

*addendum*

I do not catch properly your requirement, but in any case I will introduce a more geometric approach
to the problem that might offer a different view of the solutions.

Each  double inequality represent a stripe comprised between two parallel lines with constant separation.
The two stripes overlap to define a parallelogram, which is just translated while maintaining its shape unaltered.

[image: Diseq_Sist_3]

The coordinates of the four vertices are
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
   {} & &  {Vsi} & {Vss} & {Vii} & {Vis}  \\
\hline
   x & &  {9a + 3b - 8} & {9a + 3b - 6} & {9a + 3b - 2} & {9a + 3b}  \\
   y & &  { - 6a + 5} & { - 6a + 4} & { - 6a + 1} & { - 6a}  \\
\end{array}
$$
Now, until the x of $Vsi$ is greater than $1$ the whole parallelogram $P$ will be out of the rectangle $R = [0,1] \times [0,2]$.
Same if the y of $Vsi$ is below zero.
So to have solutions it shall be
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le b \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  9a + 3b - 8 \le 1 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le  - 6a + 5 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le b \le 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a \le 1 - b/3 \hfill \cr 
  a \le 5/6 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le b \le 1/2\; \wedge \;0 \le a \le 5/6 \hfill \cr 
  1/2 < b \le 2\; \wedge \;0 \le a \le 1 - b/3 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
Note that the above is a necessary condition yet not sufficient.
That's because when the upper vertex is in the second quadrant we have still to impose
that $P$ intersects $R$, which is as complicated as to use the previous min/max conditions.

Comment: the  $m,n$ depend  on $y$ but final answer must be in terms $a$ and $b$ only.

Comment: @Leox: added a note to reply to you comment

Comment: @G Cab I  added  P.S. with the solution for $a=0.63, b=0.59$. How do you get the same solution by your method?

Comment: @Leox: I re-shaped the answer to make it better readable and added example

Comment: @G Cab please read my edited question

Comment: @Leox: sorry but I do not grasp what you want actually to get. However I added a geometric perspective of the problem, might that help ?

Comment: @G Cab Thank you. in any case, your attempt helped me

Comment: glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

$9a+3b-8\leq x \leq9a+3b$

$-6a \leq y \leq 5-6a$

These are the equations, and there are constraints

$0≤x≤1$

$0≤y≤2$

$0≤a≤1$

$0≤b≤1$

The intersect can exist or not depending to a and b.

The graph will help:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9dbajg4hcx

The blue part is the result, and the green part are constraints.

Comment: Yours system has no solutions. In fact \begin{cases} y\leq 5-6a,\\ y \leq 2 \end{cases} $ \implies a\geq \frac{1}{2}$. But then $x \leq 9a+3b \leq \frac{9}{2}+3 b \implies x > \frac{9}{2} >1$  but must be $x\leq 1.$